# Why does Hermione say "Forget it" about Hagrid's mother when she couldn't have known before that she was dead?

Tags: harry-potter

In Goblet of fire, chapter 23 (Yule Ball) we hear Hagrid talking about his family for the first time.

> “It was my mother,” said Hagrid quietly. “She was one o’ the las’
>   ones in Britain. ’Course, I can’ remember her too well . . . she left,
>   see. When I was abou’ three. She wasn’ really the maternal sort. Well . . . it’s not in their natures, is it? Dunno what happened to
>   her . . . might be dead fer all I know. . . .”

And then we get some more details from Rita Skeeter in the next chapter (Rita Skeeter's Scoop)

> His mother,
>   we can exclusively reveal, is none other than the
>   giantess Fridwulfa, whose whereabouts are currently
>   unknown. . . .  While many of the giants who served He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named
>   were killed by Aurors working
>   against the Dark Side, Fridwulfa was not
>   among them. It is possible she escaped to one of
>   the giant communities still existing in foreign
>   mountain ranges.

So we know that neither Hagrid nor Harry, Ron or Hermione know the fate of Hagrid's Mom. And then in Order of Phoenix, chapter 20 (Hagrid's Tale)  Hermione says,

> “Hagrid?” said Hermione quietly after a while.
>   “Mmm?”
>   “Did you . . . was there any sign of . . . did you hear anything about
>   your . . . your . . . mother while you were there?”

Naturally after hearing where he had gone she was curious to know if he managed to meet his mother. And then immediately after that she says:

> Hagrid’s unobscured eye rested upon her, and Hermione looked
>   rather scared.
>   **“I’m sorry . . . I . . . forget it —”**
>   “Dead,” Hagrid grunted. “Died years ago. They told me.”
>   “Oh . . . I’m . . . I’m really sorry,” said Hermione in a very small
>   voice.

She says "I forgot". But when did she learn about the fate of Hagrid's mother when till the fourth book they were not sure if she is dead or alive?

Comment: In your citation, assuming it is correct, you say that she says "forget it" and not "I forgot".

Comment: I'm glad that the German translators of Harry Potter did not keep this written accent. It's so difficult to read.

Comment: @Fabian For someone with English as their first language (or at least, someone from Britain) it's not too difficult, and it's nice to see that linguistic diversity in print. Is there not a German equivalent that could have been used? Swabian?

Comment: There are many different accents in Germany, but I don't know which one would correspond to the one Hagrid has or how that would be written.

Comment: "forget it" means "*you* should forget I said that", not "*I* forgot". This is based on a misunderstanding of the text.

Comment: @Fabian Pick one of them. Saxonian? Bavarian? Colognian? I'll leave it to your imagination now.

Comment: She's a smart girl. From Hagrid's reaction, she guessed that Hagrid's mother is dead

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misreading/misunderstanding of the text.

Comment: @MarkBeadles - that is *not* a reason to VTC. That is a reason to possibly *downvote*, and correct the misreading through an answer.

Comment: @Mithrandir Since this is based on a misreading, the question (in my opinion) is **not relevant to more people than just OP**. That's a sufficient reason to *vote* to close. It's only a vote; it takes 4 more people to agree with me to actually close the question.

Comment: @MarkBeadles - why is it being only relevant to the OP a reason to close? Other, future users may have the same misunderstanding.

Comment: @Mithrandir From the Stack Exchange guidelines: "Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you." Regardless, though, like I said: that's just my opinion. If 4 others don't agree with me, the question stays open - I'm not clear why you are disputing a single vote to close.

Comment: @Mithrandir Only being relevant to the OP is a reason to close _because_ other, future users would not have the same misunderstanding. Whether the assertion that it is only relevant to the OP is valid is the question.

Comment: @Mithrandir If it were at home anywhere, it would be *English Language Learners* rather than Sci-Fi as the question is about "forget it" rather than about Harry Potter, but it is even off-topic there as it's covered by a [quick dictionary lookup](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forget-it)

Comment: @MarkBeadles - That's not a close reason. You can't just make them up

Comment: wow, this question got zero upvote, meanwhile the answer got like a hundreds, wth...

Answer (score 99, accepted):

> “I’m sorry . . . I . . . forget it —”

This depicts Hermione attempting 2 different methods of apology for stepping on such an emotional landmine for Hagrid, until finally giving up and trying to put the interaction behind them.

1. **I'm sorry** for mentioning anything
2. **I** *didn't realise it was an upsetting question* (or something to that nature)
3. Never mind Hagrid, please **forget it** that I said anything in the first place.